# How to convert XML to a HTML table using XSL for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert some XML with XSL, to make the output look better and more readable for other users. I have some XML along the lines of:

```
<G>
  <OE>
    <example1>Sample 1</example1>
    <example2>Sample 2</example2>
    <var name="name1">
      <integer>1</integer>
    </var>
  </OE>
</G>
```

I want to get all the details from it and display it in a table so I use the following XSL code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#3399FF">
            <th>Example 1</th>
            <th>Example 2</th>
            <th>Var name</th>
            <th>Int</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="G/OE">
            <xsl:for-each select="var">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Example 1" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Example 2" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="integer" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know that the following XSL won't work properly. I want the output to be:

Sample 1, Sample 2, name1, 1 - in a table format.

My problem is I don't know how to do this. In the above XSL code it will only retrieve var and integer. If I only use the top `<xsl:for-each>`, then only the first two are retrieved.

I have tried moving the 2nd `<xsl:for-each>` after the first to have been selected, so between:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="Example 2"/></td>
```

and

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
```

I get an error. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've cleaned up the first block of XML, showing how to enter code.

Comment: You need to 1. Show what output you expect and 2. give the error.

Comment: When you say "I want the output to be: Sample 1, Sample 2, name1, 1 - in a table format" do you mean you want each of those four pieces of text to appear with the same level of formatting, ie as peers?

Comment: This question does not make a lot of sense, because a) you seemingly have not yet decided how *exactly* your output table should look like and b) you seem confused about how XPath works. Maybe you should try to solve the atomic/fundamental parts of your problem first, before trying a complete "convert all of this to a table" solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping (in the inner for-each) over var, so both example tags are outside your scope at that point. You may want to remove the inner for-each loop (and refer to var/@name and var/integer instead of @name and integer).

Comment: for-eaches, don't loop, they visit each node (in context) in the tree.